# Filter for timeline_type in Stack Exchange API

Tags: support, api, filtering

I am using the Stack Exchange API to retrieve data about activities on Stack Overflow. Specifically, I want to retrieve the event history for a question using the endpoint:

```
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/{id}/timeline?site=stackoverflow
```

The returned list contains events with different `timeline_type`s. I would like to filter out events based on this type, for example events of type `vote_aggregate`. The filters provided by the Stack Exchange API (cf. https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/filters), however, seem to work only on properties within events (e.g., filter all properties `timeline_type` across all events).

Is there another way for me to filter out complete events with certain types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no way to limit the result types returned for this route, although I agree having this functionality for this and other endpoints would be nice.

Instead you'll have to request everything and filter them on the receiving end. In general there's usually not *that* many timeline events anyway, so while it's a little inconvenient it shouldn't hurt anything performance-wise.

Comment: Thanks @tim-stone for the answer. Timeline events can, unfortunately, be plentiful in some cases, especially `vote_aggregate` events are very frequent for popular questions. I will work around it on the receiving end as you propose, though.